# generate XML with nested parameter in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to generate an XML with parameter by parsing the following xml. i am working in c#.net.

```
<root>
    <name1>
        <names>
           <id>5</id>
           <class>space</class>
           <from>Germany</from>
           <to>France</to>
           <through>
               <via>
                   <id>4</id>
                   <route>Zurich<route>
               </via>
               <via>
                   <id>7</id>
                   <route>Vienna<route>
               </via>
           </through>           
        </names>
    </name1>
    <name2>
      <newNames>
          <id>8</id>
          <path>Road</path>
          <dest>USA</dest>
          <through>
              <route1>
                  <id>5</id>
                  <naviagte>Britain</naviagte>
              </route1>
              <route1>
                  <id>2</id>
                  <naviagte>Canada</naviagte>
              </route1>
          </through>              
      </newNames>
    </name2>
</root>
```

i want to convert it like following-

```
<root>
        <name1>
            <names id = "5";class = "space"; from = "Germany" ; to = "France">    
                <through>
                   <via id = "4" ; route = "Zurich">                                       
                   <via id = "7" ; route = "Vienna">        
               </through>           
            </names>
        </name1>
        <name2>
          <newNames id = "8"; path = "Road"; dest = "USA">
          <newNames id = "8"; path = "Road"; dest = "USA">
          <through>
               <route1 = id = "5" ; naviagte = "Britain">
               <route1 = id = "2" ; naviagte = "Canada">
          </through>              
        </name2>
    </root>
```

i have tried the following codes.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("xml_file.xml");
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
var names = doc.Descendants("name");
var newRootElement = new XElement("root");
foreach (var name in names)
{
    var newNameElement = new XElement(name.Name);
    foreach (var element in name.Elements())
    {
        newNameElement.SetAttributeValue(element.Name, element.Value);
    }
    newRootElement.Add(newNameElement);
}
Console.WriteLine(newRootElement.ToString());
newRootElement.Save("converted_xml_file.xml");
```

but i can't parse all the nodes. could anyone give me any hints or correction in my codes please ?

Comment: Is there an error? If yes, where is the error occuring?

Comment: You have `;` symbols in expected xml. Also `newNames` tag is duplicated and not closed

Comment: Also you have not closed `route` tags. Please, provide valid xml

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have closed `route` tags in your input xml. If so, then you can build new xml by querying original xml and replacing elements with attributes:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("xml_file.xml");
var root =
    new XElement("root",
        from name in xdoc.Root.Elements()
        select new XElement(name.Name,
            from names in name.Elements()
            select new XElement(names.Name,
                from namesElement in names.Elements()
                where namesElement.Name.LocalName != "through"
                select new XAttribute(namesElement.Name.LocalName, (string)namesElement),
                new XElement("through",
                    from route in names.Element("through").Elements()
                    select new XElement(route.Name,
                        from routeElement in route.Elements()
                        select new XAttribute(routeElement.Name.LocalName, (string)routeElement))))));
```

This code produces following xml:

```
<root>
  <name1>
    <names id="5" class="space" from="Germany" to="France">
      <through>
        <via id="4" route="Zurich" />
        <via id="7" route="Vienna" />
      </through>
    </names>
  </name1>
  <name2>
    <newNames id="8" path="Road" dest="USA">
      <through>
        <route1 id="5" naviagte="Britain" />
        <route1 id="2" naviagte="Canada" />
      </through>
    </newNames>
  </name2>
</root>
```

Comment: nice shoot within this given time,

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy, i corrected the tags. can you post all the codes that you used to produce this above output ?

Comment: is it possible to convert this xml format to sqlite database ? any hints would be highly appreciated :)